# Can you "Hear back"?

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

I am almost sure what will be the answer to this question, but still wanted to ask it anyways.

Can you use "hear back from sb" in a sentence?
Let's say something like:

> We have not **heard back from** you regarding ...

or should it be just:

> We have not **heard from** you regarding ...

I checked a few dictionary sources but I couldn't find "hear back":
http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hear
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hear

Comment: 'Hear back from' is grammatical and idiomatic. It is probably the preferred form when speaking about a reply.

Comment: "I heard back from my investigator."
https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-translation/hear-back-from-someone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are OK, but they have slightly different meanings. In the case of *heard back from*, there is the implication that the speaker had spoken/written to the person already, and was expecting a response. In the case of *heard from*, it simply means that the speaker was expecting a call from the person, not necessarily that there had been an earlier communication to which they were expecting a response.

So *heard back from* is somewhat more restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

The *back* means "in response to a previous communication". The Ngram viewer finds a use from [US News & World Report](https://books.google.com/books?id=TOBVAAAAYAAJ&q=%22hear%20back%20from%22&dq=%22hear%20back%20from%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif16vE4eTOAhVEQiYKHXjiD8kQ6AEIMDAF) from 1955, so people have been hearing back from others for some time now.

Comment: Am I going to hear back from you anytime soon? :-)

Comment: @RichardKayser You will. (in Batman voice)

Comment: @NVZ You're quite the movie aficionado. :-) Thanks for the "omnivorous comment". I was trying to snatch a few SE moments on my iPhone and misfired.